# System.Linq problems

Tags: html, asp.net, linq, codedom

I'm making a website with HTML **ASPX** and **C#** together with another person.
He made a lot of progress and shared it with me through **GitHub**, however the `using System.Linq;` in my project errors with

> 'the type or namespace `Linq` does not exist in the namespace `System`
> (are you missing an assembly reference?)'

It does work fine in his project strangely enough,
so I added the assemblies to the `Web.Config`. Now it seems to work on all pages except for `Default.aspx.cs`, which still gives the same error?

Could someone help me out? If there's anything else I need to provide please let me know.

Edit:

[image]

I also found this error. It probably is what causes the linq problems in the first place.

Comment: Which version of VS are you using? LINQ has been there since C# 3 / VS2008.

Comment: Which .net framework version are you on?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Visual Studio 2017 Professional

Comment: @vc74     <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>

Comment: @BrianBoddaert that's the runtime version. What is the .NET Framework version in project properties? And make sure your project has a reference to System.Core

Comment: @ThomasLevesque .NET Framework 4.6.1, what kind of reference do you mean? where would I find or put it?

Comment: Right click the "References" node in your project in the solution explorer, and select "Add reference"

Comment: The error message suggests that there might be an issue with the assembly reference for System.Linq in your Default.aspx.cs file, and possibly a separate issue with the assembly reference for Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform in your project. First, make sure that your Default.aspx.cs file has the correct assembly reference to System.Linq.